Splidejs and bootstrap tabs that become accordion: tab content is not displayed when switching from mobile to desktop
I started using this codebase to create bootstrap tabs that become accordions on mobile, and I use splidejs to give them autoplay: https://codepen.io/Haimdal/pen/oNyeQaY
Everything works fine, except that when I switch to mobile resolution and then pass the 991px breakpoint, the tab content doesn't show up. It is as if it is not synchronised with splidejs
<ul class="nav nav-pills d-none d-lg-flex mb-1" id="pills-tab" role="tablist">
  <li class="nav-item" role="presentation">
    <button class="nav-link active" id="tab1-tab" data-bs-toggle="pill" data-bs-target="#tab1" type="button" role="tab" aria-controls="tab1" aria-selected="true">Tab 1</button>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item" role="presentation">
    <button class="nav-link" id="tab2-tab" data-bs-toggle="pill" data-bs-target="#tab2" type="button" role="tab" aria-controls="tab2" aria-selected="false">Tab 2</button>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item" role="presentation">
    <button class="nav-link" id="tab3-tab" data-bs-toggle="pill" data-bs-target="#tab3" type="button" role="tab" aria-controls="tab3" aria-selected="false">Tab 3</button>
  </li>    
</ul>

<div class="splide splide__slider" aria-label="Placeholder Label">
    <div id="tabData" class="tab-content accordion">
      <div id="toggle-track" class="splide__track">
        <!-- TAB 1 -->
        <div class="splide__list">
          <div class="splide__slide">
            <div class="tab-pane fade show active accordion-item" id="tab1" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="tab1-tab" tabindex="0">
              <h2 class="accordion-header d-lg-none" id="headingOne">
                <button class="accordion-button" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#collapseOne" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapseOne">
                  Accordion 1
                </button>
              </h2>
              <div id="collapseOne" class="accordion-collapse collapse show d-lg-block my-1 my-lg-0" aria-labelledby="headingOne" data-bs-parent="#tabData">
                <div class="accordion-body my-1 my-lg-0">
                  <div class="container">
                    <div class="row my-lg-1">
                      <!-- My content -->
                    </div><!-- /row -->
                  </div><!-- /container -->
                </div><!-- /accordion-body -->
              </div><!-- /accordion-collapse -->
            </div><!-- /tab-pane -->
          </div><!-- /splide__slide -->

          <!-- TAB 2 -->
          <div class="splide__slide">
            <div class="tab-pane fade accordion-item" id="tab2" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="tab2-tab" tabindex="0">
              <h2 class="accordion-header d-lg-none" id="headingTwo">
                <button class="accordion-button collapsed" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#collapseTwo" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseTwo">
                  Accordion 2
                </button>
              </h2>
              <div id="collapseTwo" class="accordion-collapse collapse d-lg-block" aria-labelledby="headingTwo" data-bs-parent="#tabData">
                <div class="accordion-body my-1 my-lg-0">
                  <div class="container">
                    <div class="row my-lg-1">
                      <!-- My Content -->
                    </div><!-- /row -->
                  </div><!-- /container -->
                </div><!-- /accordion-body -->
              </div><!-- /accordion-collapse -->
            </div><!-- /tab-pane -->
          </div><!-- /splide__slide -->

          <!-- TAB 3 -->
          <div class="splide__slide">
            <div class="tab-pane fade accordion-item" id="tab3" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="tab3-tab" tabindex="0">
              <h2 class="accordion-header d-lg-none" id="headingThree">
                <button class="accordion-button collapsed" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#collapseThree" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseThree">
                  Accordion 3
                </button>
              </h2>
              <div id="collapseThree" class="accordion-collapse collapse d-lg-block" aria-labelledby="headingThree" data-bs-parent="#tabData">
                <div class="accordion-body my-1 my-lg-0">
                  <div class="container">
                    <div class="row my-lg-1">
                      <!-- My content -->
                    </div><!-- /row -->
                  </div><!-- /container -->
                </div><!-- /accordion-body -->
              </div><!-- /accordion-collapse -->
            </div><!-- /tab-pane -->
          </div><!-- /splide__slide -->          
        </div><!-- /splide__list -->
      </div><!-- /splide__track -->      
    </div><!-- /tab-content -->
  </div><!-- /splide__slider -->

const splide = new Splide('.splide', {
    type: 'fade',
    rewind: true,
    speed: 700,
    arrows: false,
    autoplay: true,
    pagination: false,
    pauseOnFocus: true,    
    breakpoints: {
      991: {
        destroy: true,
      },
    },
  });

  splide.mount();
  const { Drag } = splide.Components;
  Drag.disable(true);
  
  splide.on('moved', function (newIndex) {
    const tabElement = document.getElementById(`tab${newIndex + 1}-tab`);

    if (tabElement) {
      new bootstrap.Tab(tabElement).show();
    }
  });
  
  document.querySelectorAll('[data-bs-toggle="pill"]').forEach((tab, index) => {
    tab.addEventListener('click', () => {      
      const slideIndex = index;
      if (slideIndex >= 0 && slideIndex < splideDatiRGS.length) splideDatiRGS.go(slideIndex);      
    });
  });

